# manual reset relay

Tags: relay

I am looking to get some help on something. I am trying to set up a system for our CMM's at work. The machine will crash itself if the air pressure is drained too slowly, but if you shut it off fast then it is fine. I found an air pressure switch from Parker and a normally closed solenoid valve. I thought the other day one thing I would like to add to the system. I would really like to get a relay that if I were to forget to turn everything off at the end of the day it won't automatically come back on the next time the air pressure reaches the correct limit. So if I loose air pressure once then I have to go back and "cycle the breaker" for it to work.

I am trying to keep everything on 120VAC to not have to use a transformer.

Comment: what exact task do you want your mechanism to perform?

Comment: If you're not a licenced electrician you really doen't want to be messing with 120V at your workplace for legal reasons.  so using a 24V transformer is generally to be preferred.

Comment: I am trying to make a mechanical check for our air system. If the air pressure is over 80 psi. You can push a button and the  air valve will open. If the air pressure drops below 80 psi the air valve will close and go to safe mode. The switch I asked about will also make the system not cycle on and off everyday if I forget to turn off the main power or close the main valve before this "system check".

Comment: use Charles's circuit below. connect the pressure switch in series with the stop button.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you want a 3-wire, momentary-contact, run/stop pushbutton circuit as shown below except using a relay with a 120 VAC coil.

[image]